# bonnmotion installation in ubuntu 16.04 java binary path error

Tags: java

i try to installing Bonnmotion and while trying to run the application from terminal following error was displayed: please enter Java Binary path. Where is Java binary located and how am I suppose to troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: "please enter java binary path" ??

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy and paste it as a quote. Text in images is harder to read, not searchable and inaccessible for screen readers.

Answer (score 4):

At first you need to install Java:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre default-jdk
```

the command above will install (among others) `java` and `javac` to `/usr/bin`.

Then download your software and launch its `install` script:

```
wget http://sys.cs.uos.de/bonnmotion/src/bonnmotion-2.1a.zip
unzip bonnmotion-2.1a.zip
cd bonnmotion-2.1a
./install # hit enter on "Please enter your Java binary path [/usr/bin]:"
```

The executable will be available as `./bin/bm`.

**Note:** newer 3.0.1 version compiles normally too.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type `echo $PATH` and see what the results are. My Java path in Ubuntu 16.04 is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Then you can browse in Files file manager to check if java is in the same location in your Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Too difficult. `which java` and `which javac` are enough.